# Tensorboard displays blank webpage on windows OS

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.5, tensorboard

I have tensorflow version 0.12 installed on windows 8.1
I'm using anaconda with python 3.5.2 64 bit.

I used the source code below.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.12/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py

2 folder had been generated

```
E:\tmp\tensorflow\mnist\logs\mnist_with_summaries\train
E:\tmp\tensorflow\mnist\logs\mnist_with_summaries\test
```

I cd to

```
 E:\tmp\tensorflow\mnist\logs\mnist_with_summaries\
```

i ran the code

```
tensorboard --logdir=train
```

[image]

i opened google chrome browser page is empty
[image]

i have included the source code of the page

```
<!doctype html>
<!--
@license
Copyright 2016 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
-->

<html>
  <head>
    <title>TensorBoard</title>
    <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/css/global.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plottable/plottable.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/png;base64,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">
    <link rel="import" href="dist/bazel-html-imports.html">
    <link rel="import" href="dist/tf-tensorboard.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <tf-tensorboard></tf-tensorboard>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am i missing or What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The same thing works on linux (debian) in firefox, although I did have to enable localhost in noscript. Afterwards the page loads fine. Can there be anything blocking JS on localhost? It also takes ~10-15 seconds to load.

Comment: i checked the console on chome its not blocked. I just installed firefox i get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working with the nightly build. i found the link from

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/5844

Answer (score 1):

I had version 0.12.0 installed under Anaconda on Windows and I was getting exactly this. I upgraded to version 1.0 and then it worked fine, but it was a bit of an adventure getting there.

When I first tried:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

it did not work, the process errored out with the message:

> Cannot remove entries from nonexistent file c:\program
>   files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\easy-install.pth

I followed a couple of false leads, but eventually I got rid of the easy-install problem with:

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade pip setuptools
```

Then the above TensorFlow upgrade did run and the new TensorFlow version was 1.0.1 and TensorBoard worked as well.

Comment: Just upgrading, what you first tried, did it for me: pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow

Comment: tensorflow is maturing... glad your experience was better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by pasting the log folder directly on drive C, so I limited the number of backslashes. Path was short and it worked just fine.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.